# Converting UnixTime to day intervals (morning, evening, night etc.) in R

Tags: r, unix-timestamp

I have a table with a column TIMESTAMP with Unix Time values. I need to convert it to intervals of day, like night, morning, before_afternoon, afternoon, twilight, evening.

```
data$TIMESTAMP[1]
[1] 1372636858
time <- anytime(1372636858)
> time
[1] "2013-07-01 01:00:58 WEST"
```

I am doing:

```
cut(time, breaks= as.POSIXct(paste("2001-01-01",c("00:00:00", "06:00:00", "09:00:00","12:00:00","15:00:00","18:00:00", "20:00:00")),format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz ="Portugal"),labels=c('night','morning','before_afternoon','afternoon','twilight','evening'))
```

The output is:

```
[1] <NA>
Levels: night morning before_afternoon afternoon twilight evening
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: It is not working because the dates are different (2013-07-01 and 2001-01-01).  You probably need to just strip off the time element.

Comment: I'd try `c('night','morning','before_afternoon','afternoon','twilight','evening')[findInterval(as.POSIXlt(time)$hour,c(0,6,9,15,18,20))]`.

Comment: It worked in this way!!!! Exactly that I needed. Thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'd try c('night','morning','before_afternoon','afternoon','twilight‌​','evening')[findInt‌​erval(as.POSIXlt(tim‌​e)$hour,c(0,6,9,15,1‌​8,20))]. – nicola Jun 1 at 11:06